# Why my school network blocking my login to aws ec2 with putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, putty

I tried to log in to my aws ec2 instance with putty. Every time I connect to my school wifi it keeps saying connection Time Out. But when I try to connect with my phone network it's working fine again.

I already set the security inbound rules to everyone, only myIP. but still not working.

Here is the error... "Network error!!!Connection Time Out"

Comment: When you say everyone, that means IPv4 and IPv6 right? if possible, Can you show us the Security Group Configuration of your EC2 instance?

Comment: Inbound Rules - Custom TCP Rule          TCP            8080              0.0.0.0/0
Custom TCP Rule           TCP           8080                ::/0
SSH                                TCP            22                  0.0.0.0/0
SSH                                TCP            22                    ::/0                                              These are Outbound Rules          -                                                                                        All traffic                           All              All                  0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 1):

Your School wifi  must be operating behind a firewall and traffic is filtered. For example - in most companies only few sites are allowed to browse and rest all are blocked by firewall rules.

Comment: Is there any way I could solve this from my side?

Comment: you need to get the ip address white listed from the company security team.

Answer (score 0):

Port 22 is blocked in most of public networks. You can try connecting putty after connecting from your mobile network.

Comment: I tried that. but not working.